# Trying to code the nearest neighbours algorithm - euclidean distance function only calculates the distances for one row of the test set - why?

Tags: python, algorithm, indexing, euclidean-distance

I am trying to code the Nearest Neighbours Algorithm from scratch and have come across a problem - my algorithm was only giving the index/classification of the nearest neighbour for one row/point of the the training set. I went through every part of my code and realised that the problem is my Euclidean distance function. It only gives the result for one row.

This is the code I have written for Euclidean distance:

```
def euclidean_dist(r1, r2):
    dist = 0
    for j in range(0, len(r2)-1):
        dist = dist + (r2[j] - r1[j])**2
    return dist**0.5
```

Within my Nearest Neighbours algorithm this is the implementation of the Euclidean distance function:

```
for i in range(len(x_test)):
        dist1 = []
        dist2 = []
        for j in range(len(x_train)):
            distances = euclidean_dist(x_test[i], x_train[j,:])
            dist1.append(distances)
            dist2.append(distances)
        dist1 = np.array(dist1)
        sorting(dist1) #separate sorting function to sort the distances from lowest to highest,
#the aim was to get one array, dist1, with the euclidean distances for each row sorted
#and one array with the unsorted euclidean distances, dist2, (to be able to search for index later in the code)
```

I noticed the problem when using the iris dataset and trying out this part of the function with it. I split the data set into testing and training (`X_test`, `X_train` and `y_test`).

When this was implemented with the data set I got the following array for `dist2`:

```
[0.3741657386773946,
 1.643167672515499,
 3.389690251335658,
 2.085665361461421,
 1.284523257866513,
 3.9572717874818752,
 0.9539392014169458,
 3.5805027579936315,
 0.7211102550927979,
      ...
0.8062257748298555,
 0.4242640687119287,
 0.5196152422706631]
```

Its length is 112 which is the same length as `X_train`, but these are only the Euclidean distances for the first row or point of the `X_test` set. The `dist1` array is the same except it is sorted.

Why am I not getting the Euclidean distances for every row/point of the test set? I thought I iterated through correctly with the for loops, but clearly something is not quite right. Any advice or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Every iteration on x_test, you reset dist1 and dist2. Hence you only have the last one. Btw you should really switch do numpy array for this kind of calculation.

Comment: How do I make it to where dist1 and dist2 are not reset each iteration? How would I use numpy array to improve this?

Answer (score 0):

Using numpy for speed, built-in distance, and code length:

```
x_test_array = np.array(x_test)
x_train_array = np.array(x_train)
distance_matrix = np.linalg.norm(x_test[:,np.newaxis,:]-x_train[np.newaxis,:,:], axis=2)
```

Cell i,j in the matrix corresponds to the distance between x_train[i] and x_test[j].
You can then do sorting.

Edit: How to create the distance matrix without numpy:

```
matrix = []
for i in range(len(x_test)):
    dist1 = []
    for j in range(len(x_train)):
        distances = euclidean_dist(x_test[i], x_train[j,:])
        dist1.append(distances)
    matrix.append(dist1)
```

Comment: Hi - is there a way to do this using my code for Euclidean distance instead of the np.linalg.norm and still creating a matrix? I don't think I am supposed to be using that in this task.
As well as this - in np.linalg.norm code you provided, why is x_test not included in it?

Comment: That was typo sorry fixed it. Without numpu you can create a list of lists. Create a list before the first for loop and call it matrix. Then at the end of each loop on i, append  dist to the matrix.

Comment: I tried appending the list in my original code to an empty list, but clearly I did not implement it correctly. Is there another way to append it that I do not know about? Thank you for your help!